# Passando endereço para WriteProcessMemory

Tags: c, c++, memória

Estou tentando passar um endereço de memória para `WriteProcessMemory()`, só que este endereço deve ser digitado pelo usuário, estou com dúvida de como posso fazer isso, eu tentei com *strings*, `wstring`, não tive sucesso.

```
int isSuccessful = WriteProcessMemory(hproc, /*VALOR DIGITADO PELO USUARIO(LPVOID)0x002bf55c*/, &NewValue, (DWORD)sizeof(NewValue), NULL);
```

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 3):

Você tem certeza que deseja fazer isto? Parece que você está querendo fazer algo bem avançado e perigoso e está tendo uma dúvida muito básica. Esta combinação não costuma dar certo.

A aplicação tem permissão de escrita nesta área da memória? Por sorte o sistema operacional controla isto e ainda bem que não deixar a aplicação escrever em qualquer parte da memória. Você não pode escrever em outras aplicações e nem mesmo em certas partes da sua própria aplicação.

As variáveis usadas foram corretamente *setadas*? Vou considerar que sim, afinal você não colocou todo trecho do programa e deve considerar que há um problema apenas nesta linha.

Então basta ler um **inteiro** e usá-lo como ponteiro conforme você já estava tentando fazer. Provavelmente o problema é que estava lendo uma *string*.

```
int endereco;
scanf("%d", &endereco);
int isSuccessful = WriteProcessMemory(hproc, (LPVOID)endereco, &NewValue, (DWORD)sizeof(NewValue), NULL);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Library/WriteMemory.cpp).

Comment: mais e o hexa ?

Comment: 0xENDEREÇO, não passa como string?

Comment: eu já tentei fazer desse jeito também que você passou.
o endereço possui caracteres, fiquei na duvida agora.
ex: 0x002BF55C

Comment: ou, eu não preciso passa-lo como hexadecimal?

Comment: Então seu problema é outro, você precisa de um conversor de *string* em formato hexadecimal para um número inteiro para usar em algum lugar, não importa o lugar. O que você perguntou eu respondi. Se você ainda precisa saber como fazer o conversor veja se não tem respondido no *site*. Se não tiver faça uma pergunta pedindo isto.

Comment: quando eu uso o seguinte (LPVOID)0x002bf55c, funciona 
porém ter que ficar compilando o código e trocando esse valor toda hora é bem chato, por isso estou tentando fazer de uma maneira em que eu possa fornecer este valor durante o programa